# Release Itunes app name for others to use

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Our organization has created an app for a client.  Now, our client is hiring a different organization to build their app.  They want to use the exact same name for the app, and are encountering 'This app name is taken' errors when attempting to create it.

The other organization also refuses to give us the information required to transfer the existing app over to them.

Can anyone say for sure, or know where in the documentation it may be explicitly stated that deleting the app altogether from our account will free up the name so they can use it?

The only other alternative is to re-submit our app under a different name, but this obviously takes far longer, given we'd need to go through the app approval or rejection process again for this to happen.  I feel like the logical thing to do is simply delete our app, but I cannot find it explicitly stated anywhere that this will free the reserved app name.

Comment: You can only delete an app, if you submitted it successfully once. (Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted)

Comment: Our app has been submitted successfully before, and so is capable of being deleted.  Question is, it is faster to re-submit app with a new name, or delete the app altogether, to free up the reserved app name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fastest way is to transfer the app to new profile,
2. You can delete the app (once deleted from your account, new organization can use the same app ID,  however i don't recommended deletion as it's irreversible process and you cannot use the same name ever - **Important:  If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.**). So if in future client wants to use your profile again, he/she cannot. Also need to consult with apple as i feel even bundle ID cannot be used by different organization.
3. Rename the app - Safest option in your case I feel is this. Remove app from sales and then simply rename app to **existingappname**1 ( add a number at end of app and new user will be able to use existing name).

**In Any case delete should be very last option to be used.**

Complete process for rename / transfer and delete explain here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html